# How to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n^2x}$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

I know the series is pointwise convergent on $(0,\infty)$ and that it is uniformly convergent on $[a,\infty)$ for any $a>0$ but I'm not sure how to prove it is continuous on $(0,\infty)$.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You say you know it's continuous on $[a,\infty)$ for any $a>0$. This means it's continuous on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: An approach would be to argue that the $f_n$ are continuous, then uniform convergence implies continuity.

Comment: In a previous problem I found that the series is only uniformly convergent (and hence continuous) on [a,infinity] for any a>0.  But pointwise continuous on (0,infinity).  I don't think I can conclude from that that the series is continuous on (0,infinity)

Comment: You say you know it's continuous on $[a,\infty)$ for every $a>0$. What does this mean? If a function (whether it is defined as the limit of a series or not) is continuous in $[a,\infty)$ for every $a>0$ then it is also continuous in $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: To show @Snaw's reasoning : let $x_0\in (0,\infty)$, we wish to establish $f$ is continuous at this point, if this is true for every point then the function will be continuous on the interval.  For this $x_0$, there is $0<a_0<x_0$ and by your argument, $f$ is continuous on $[a_0,\infty)$ so it is continuous at $x_0$ and hence on $(0,\infty)$

Comment: You have uniform convergence which should allow you to bring the $x$ limit inside the sum so you can prove continuity.

Comment: To prove continuity at a point $x \in (0,+\infty)$, it suffices to show the series converges uniformly on some neighborhood of $x$.  You have all the ingredients to do that.

Comment: Thank you @Nick Castillo for clarifying. It all makes sense now! Thanks guys!

Comment: You can also get the sum in the closed form. Using $\,\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{a^2+n^2}=\frac{\pi}{a}\coth\pi a$
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{1+n^2x}=\frac{1}{2x}\big(\pi\sqrt x\coth\frac{\pi}{\sqrt x}-x\big)=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt x}\cot\frac{\pi}{\sqrt x}-\frac{1}{2}$$
The result follows.